# Basic Attoparsec Parsing returns only "Right []"

Tags: haskell, text-parsing

I'm very new to Haskell and I'm trying to parse a map file, just for practice. My code will compile, but it gives me the wrong result. All I get is "Right []" - which I don't understand.

My code is very similar to the tutorial [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/attoparsec), but I rewrote it to serve my needs.

My file looks like this (I removed most of the lines to save space here):

```
#test map 2
0,0:1;
1,0:1;
2,0:1;
3,0:1;
```

My code:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Time
import Data.Attoparsec.Char8
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

-- Types --

data Tile = Tile Int Int Int deriving Show

data MapLine =
  MapLine { tile :: Tile } deriving Show

-- Parsing --

parseTile :: Parser Tile
parseTile = do
  x <- decimal
  char ','
  y <- decimal
  char ':'
  t <- decimal
  char ';'
  return $ Tile x y t

mapLineParser :: Parser MapLine
mapLineParser = do
  t <- parseTile
  return $ MapLine t

fileParser :: Parser [MapLine]
fileParser = many $ mapLineParser <* endOfLine

-- Main --
main :: IO()
--main = B.readFile "map.hexmap" >>= print . parseOnly fileParser
main = do
  print "Parsing map..."
  let x = B.readFile "map.hexmap"
  x >>= print . parseOnly fileParser
  print "Done."
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parser "successfully parses" a list of MapLines of length zero before failing at the first line. Remove that line (and make sure your file doesn't include any non-parsable bytes at the start like a BOM) and it should work. Or write a parser for lines starting with a `#` that ignores the result, then combine.

Comment: I've been trying to create a parser that will ignore a #, and I can't get it to work. My parser looks like:

`skipComment :: Parser B.ByteString
skipComment = do
  char '#'
  takeTill (\x -> x == '\r' || x == '\n')`

If I add this to my mapLineParser then it just gets the "Right []" again. Do you have any advice?

Comment: `takeTill` won't consume the input that returns True, so you are left with an empty line, which your parser then fails on. Just use something like `<* endOfLine` again (or the equivalent in do notation) and it should work (if you use that parser the right way in mapLineParser at least).

Comment: I'm sorry to ask yet another question but how do I make `>>= print . parseOnly fileParser` give me a list?

Comment: Remove the print and use pattern matching on the parse result.     E. g. `x <-B.readFile "map.hexmap"` `case parseOnly fileParser x of`